# How to change text on button with pressing of different button without use of 'self' instance

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I need your help on this.

```
class SwimMenu(Screen):
 
    wDiscard = "discard"
    def falsify1(self):
        global really
        really = False
        self.parent.remove_widget(self)
        #here I need to change text on discard button


reallyButton1 = Button(pos=(0, 0.1), size_hint=(1, 0.9), text="", background_color=(0, 0, 0, 0))
reallyButton1.bind(on_release=falsify1)
```

There is my .kv file:

```
<SwimMenu>:
name: "swim"
FloatLayout:
    Button:
        id: discard
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
        pos_hint: {"x":0.8, "y":0.9}
        text: root.wDiscard
        on_release:
            root.remove()
```

Basically what I want to do is to change text on `discard button` created in .kv file after pressing `really button` which is defined in python file. I have solved it with `falsify1()` function where I am also doing some other stuff, but I couldn't find a way to change text on `discard button` as `self` instance here is referring to the button itself, which I figured might be the problem. Every solution I have googled required `self`, which doesn't work for me.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: `self` in the method referring to the `SwimMenu` instance. You need to get the `button` instance. Since it is a child of your `SwimMenu`, you want to find a way to get the children of your instance

Comment: If the `self` if referencing to the button and you want to get its parent class , I think maybe can try use `self.parent` to get its parent class ; `<instance>.children` for getting an object’s children ( if I didn’t remembering wrong ). Is it what you are looking for ?